# Google map country boundary

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using [goMap library](http://www.pittss.lv/jquery/gomap/examples.php) but seems it doesn't support query to  fusiontable. My main motive is to get coordinates of each country and draw polygon around border of selected country but since I was unable to find anything for fusiontable in goMap library I downloaded

https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1uL8KJV0bMb7A8-SkrIe0ko2DMtSypHX52DatEE4#rows:id=1

goMap library has createPolygon() builtin function so I tried  to provide coordinates manually without fusiontable query, for example I extracted Greece coordinates (using php) from downloaded fusiontable file.
http://pastebin.com/MwcHBCYA

I copied the  `<coordinates>` and used it like this to create Polygon with goMap library.

```
$.goMap.createPolygon({
    color: "#00CC00",
    fillColor: '#00CC00',
    fillOpacity:    0.2,
    weight:     2,

    coords: [{//coords here]
});
```

full code here:
http://pastebin.com/BZPkLmfM

It draw polygons 
[image]

But it doesn't draw polygons around Greece Border and it doesn't seems correct map outline for Greece.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have swapped your latitudes and longitudes. Athens is lat 37.983917, lng 23.7293599 but your coords are (example) latitude: "27.0669451586", longitude: "35.6066640463"